# ¿Por qué me han desaparecido puntos y no consta en la página de reputación?

Tags: soporte, reputación, cuentas-de-usuario

En la cuenta de Stack Overflow en español tenía más de 80 de reputación ayer. Hoy fui a mirar y tengo 28 y en ningun lado pone -50. ¿Se bugeó o qué pasó? No entiendo.

Mi pefil es: https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/61900/kevin-salazar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en https://es.stackoverflow.com/reputation me sale:

```
total votes: 0
-- 2017-11-09 rep 0 = 1
** rep today: 0
** rep this week (2017-11-26 - 2017-12-02): 0
** rep this month (2017-11-01 - 2017-11-30): 0
** rep this quarter (2017-10-01 - 2017-12-31): 0
** rep this year (2017-01-01 - 2017-12-31): 0
** rep from bonuses: 0
** total rep 1 :)

days represented 0
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes only on 0 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 0 days
earned 0 reputation from suggested edits
```

Comment: Puedes consultar la razón de esa caida en tu perfil. Pincha en la pestaña "reputación" y dentro de ahi en "tiempo". Por mi experiencia, una de dos: o recibiste puntuaciones de un mismo usuario y se consideró por el sistema "votación masiva", o se ha eliminado un usuario que te voto en varias ocasiones. Esta última es probable, en mi caso acabo de comprobar una caida de 10 puntos por la eliminación de un usuario.

Comment: no no hay caidas

Comment: Estas seguro? En tu perfil deben aparecer todos los cambios de reputación que se hayan producido. Revisa bien la pestaña que te he dicho.

Comment: te adjunto una foto

Comment: @KevinSalazar please anda a este link: https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: me apareces esto total votes: 0
-- 2017-11-09 rep 0     = 1         

** rep today: 0
** rep this week (2017-11-26 - 2017-12-02): 0
** rep this month (2017-11-01 - 2017-11-30): 0
** rep this quarter (2017-10-01 - 2017-12-31): 0
** rep this year (2017-01-01 - 2017-12-31): 0
** rep from bonuses: 0
** total rep 1 :)

days represented 0
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 0 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 0 days
earned 0 reputation from suggested edits

Comment: Tenemos a un moderador revisando, ahora te dirá algo

Comment: @KevinSalazar entonces hay algo muy extraño en todo esto, porque tu reputación debería ser claramente mayor

Comment: @KevinSalazar ¿Cuántas cuentas tienes abiertas?

Comment: 1 porque la tengo por facebook

Comment: Curioso, en la pestaña actividad pone 28 pero la grafica que hay al lado llega a los 87.

Comment: si es que esos era los que tenia anoche

Answer (score 7):

Mirando tu historial de actividad he visto que el usuario Comunidad (bot del sistema) ha juntado tu cuenta (id = 66619) con la de Alberto Campos (id = 61900).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por qué?

Al parecer ambas cuentas eran manejadas desde la misma IP y algun otro motivo que hizo que Comunidad actuara así.

Al juntarlas el sistema quita los votos que se pudieran hacer de la una hacia la otra dejando un valor menor al que tenía una por separado.

He hablado en el chat internacional de moderadores para comentar esta situación. 
Confirman que todo apunta a "sock puppeting" (varias cuentas de un mismo usuario que se vota entre si para subir de rep).

Si no fuera el caso, podemos contactar contigo por privado e intentar averiguar que pudo pasar y por qué se dió el error.

Comment: pero no pueden revisar los votos hechos y veran que no he hecho nada de eso

Comment: @KevinSalazar Te suena Alberto Campos? Tienes alguna posible explicación de porque la ip de acceso de ambos coincide?

Comment: no no me suena es mas si no me creen no pueden revisar los votos hechos

Comment: En la respuesta es toda la informacion que he podido recabar. Puedes ponerte en contacto con SE a traves de este [formulario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact). Ahi puedes enlazar esta respuesta para que alguien pueda aclarar la situación. Siento no ser de más ayuda pero seguiré investigando a ver. Un saludo

Comment: ok vale gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Kevin, lo que reportas en realidad no es un bug, es importante comentar que 6 * banderas rojas (Spam o banderas groseras o abusivas)  por parte de los usuarios de la comunidad a una publicación, en este caso una publicación que realizaste como respuesta:

[Diferencias al ejecutar una función?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/118296/diferencias-al-ejecutar-una-funci%C3%B3n/118297#118297)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la publicación se bloquea y se elimina, y  **el autor pierde 100 de reputación**. (Bloquear significa que los usuarios con el privilegio de herramientas del moderador ("10k usuarios") no pueden editarlo ni recuperarlo).

**Te aconsejamos que con las cuentas de usuario que sigues Stackoverflow en español sigas las reglas del sitio**,  [requerimos que todos los participantes se comporten de manera profesional y educada cuando usen el sitio.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Esta misma pregunta se realizo en la versión en inglés de meta:

[Why did I lose 100 reputation on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67628/why-did-i-lose-100-reputation-on-so/67629)

**"En pocas palabras :) se agradable."**

Comment: pero si yo no he respondido nada de eso

Comment: @KevinSalazar entonces la publicacion era de Alberto y al hacerse el merge, sus publicaciones son ahora bajo tu nombre.

Comment: a lo mejor no se pero yo no he respondido nada de eso si tambien la mire y aparece mi nombre pero yo no he hecho eso

Comment: @lois6b exactamente, de hecho el usuario "alberto campos" se elimino para realizar un merge el 11/30/2017

Comment: si ya se realizo el merge porque dice que a las 1:28pm de hoy?

Comment: @KevinSalazar bueno, eso será cosa de la hora UTC del servidor.

Comment: @KevinSalazar config del server como comenta lois6b

Comment: ah vale ok y entonces

Comment: @Jorgesys al final se puede solucionar algo

Comment: @KevinSalazar vamos a consultar con meta StackExchange. En cuanto sepamos algo te contactaremos. Un saludo

Comment: ok vale  no hay problema

Comment: Pones en entredicho situaciones de las cuales no tienes conocimiento, hay procesos y acciones automáticos los cuales obviamente no pueden ser difundidos, en este caso el OP requiere información para entender la duda que plantea. Lo que deben realizar los usuarios es seguir las reglas del sitio y además comportarse de manera profesional y educada. Trata de realizar anotaciones que ayuden a la comunidad y evita señalamientos no constructivos.

Comment: En verdad hay que tener mucha paciencia; bien, esto mismo se pregunto en SOen: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67628/why-did-i-lose-100-reputation-on-so/67629  **En pocas palabras :) se agradable.** ( 
In a nutshell :) be nice.)

Comment: Modifiqué la imagen, se supone no se veía, en fin.Te vuelvo a repetir, trata de ser más amable y evita criticas que no ayudan a la comunidad, trata de realizar solo criticas constructivas, no lo comento únicamente por mí, lo comentó por todas las personas a las cuales te has acercado de una forma no adecuada. Realizando criticas constructivas puedes ayudar a las personas a mejorar, nadie es perfecto, todos podemos aprender nuevas cosas, ahora hasta me has ayudado a ser mejor moderador...ᕦ ´• ᴥ •` ᕥ